# Align divs next to each other

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site where I am using shortcodes to align images in four columns. This normally works fine but for some reason each image isn't aligned directly next to the other, but instead slightly indented from the top of the other.

You can see my site as an example here: http://goo.gl/e7gUo

**Does anyone know how to fix this issue?**

The CSS for the shortcode column is currently:

```
float:left;
margin-right:4%;
position:relative;
width:22%;
```

Comment: now after you fixed your page, question doesnt make any sense

Answer (score 3):

Add:

`.one_fourth{ float: left; }`

And remove the `<br>`s between them.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `<br />` after each  block with image

Comment: Richard was first with answer :-)